# What is the splitting criterion in Regression trees (DecisionTreeRegressor sklearn) in the multi output case

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, cart

I am using DecisionTreeRegressor and RandomForestRegressor from sklearn in a case where i have multiple output, but i did not find a reference article for the regression case (which is used by sklearn).

There is one reference for classification case "FAST MULTI-CLASS IMAGE ANNOTATION WITH RANDOM
SUBWINDOWS AND MULTIPLE OUTPUT RANDOMIZED TREES" but i am looking for the regression case, more precisely i want to see how the splitting criterion is computed (the mathematical expression).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: pretty sure that is just the  (sum of) squared errors as reported in the documentation

Comment: I saw that in the documentation, but it is just the sum of squared error not average or anything else ?